# How to properly apply CSS style to H elements in ordered list

Tags: css, list, counter, css-counter

I have this small problem, I am building a nested ordered list, and I want to be able to customize the styles of top level elements (note that bold is both on the counter and text).

> **1. AAA**
>
> 1.1 Lorem ipsum
>
> 1.2 Lorem ipsum
>
> 1.3 Lorem ipsum
>
> **2. BBB**
>
> 2.1 Lorem ipsum
>
> 2.2 Lorem ipsum
>
> 2.3 Lorem ipsum

The problem I have encountered is that if I apply any `<h>` tag for the top level elements of the list, the counter breaks.

Without the `<h3>` tags counters work properly, but without  `<h3>` I am unable to style top level elements of the list.

How can I get both working counter and styled top level elements?

Sample here:

```css
#test li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#test h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#test ol, ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

#test li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

#test ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0
}

#test h3>li {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="test">
    
    <ol>
       
    <h3><li>AAAA</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
        
    <h3><li>BBBB</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
    <h3><li>CCCC</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
    </ol>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already indicated in the other two answers, the structure is wrong (invalid) as you have put a `h3` directly inside a `ol` and then added the `li` inside the `h3`. `ol` can have only `li` as direct children, so move the `h3` to be within the `li` and do the following changes to your CSS.

- Increment the counters at `#test li` instead of incrementing it as `#test li:before`. The reason for this is to have the counter's inheritance and scoping unaffected by the extra elements.
- Add the counter's value to the `#test li h3:before` element (this will add the number next to the heading and apply the same styling as the `h3` to the number also). Then we also need to display numbers at second level `li`, so add the counter display to `#test li li:before` also.

```css
#test li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px
}
#test h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#test ol, ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
#test li {
  counter-increment: item
}
#test li h3:before,
#test li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".")" ";
}
#test ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0
}
#test li > h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h3>AAAA</h3>
      <ol>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>BBBB</h3>
      <ol>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>CCCC</h3>
      <ol>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

(*Added as separate answer because the existing answers did not cover your question fully*)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it in detail. It is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You have bad formatting on your "top-level" list-elements. the < li > attribute should be outside < h3 > attribute. Check out this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqPrWb

```
<body>
<div id="test">

    <ol>

      <li>
        <h3>AAAA</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>


    <li>
      <h3>BBBB</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>

  <li>  
    <h3>CCCC</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
   </li>

    </ol>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Edit:
Use CSS :before... Check out new pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqPrWb

```
ol :before{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

This will set the font-size of all numbers in < ol >... Using classes, you can set it on specific levels of your list!

Comment: But it does not apply the style to the digit before the `<h3>`, that's why I used `<h3>` before `<li>`

Comment: Chek out my new pen! :) Using the :before property will probably help you out!

Comment: I was waiting to see your next update mate because you had got part of the answer correct but have proceeded to add my own answer because I felt the other part is still not completely answered. Didn't feel comfortable modifying your answer to include my version. But a upvote from me for addressing a very key part of the problem :)

Comment: Teamwork I guess! The important thing is helping out this guy! :P

Answer (score 2):

Your heading 3's should be nested within the list item tags.

```css
#test li {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px
}

#test h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#test ol, ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}

#test li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}

#test h3:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}


#test ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0
}

#test li>h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="test">
    
    <ol>
       
    <li><h3>AAAA</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
        
    <li><h3>BBBB</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
    <li><h3>CCCC</h3>
    <ol>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Lorem ipsum.</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    
    </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Edited so that the `h3` styles are applied to `h3' elements that are children of `li` elements.